# How to calculate Lagrange Multiplier to train SVM with QP

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am implemeting the Quadratic problem to train an SVM. I can understand **QP**. But I could not understand what is Lagrange Multipliers. Can any one tell me what is Lagrange multiplier and how to calculate the Lagrange multiplier from training examples. Thanks in advance.Quadratic problem  as follows:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems understanding something in the lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation starting on page 43 in [Lecture9.pdf](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2427/bik12/DownloadMaterial/Lectures/Lecture9.pdf) on the subject, and your quadratic problem is solved from page 50 and forward in the same lecture notes. I don't think I can explain it better then this lecture.

There also is some additional information on SVM's in the [Lecture Notes](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2427/bik12/Schedule.php)